# group by clause is not working with Image

Tags: sql-server

I want to `Select Category name, Short_Desc, categoryImage from tbl_productCategory`.
And I want to Count Total Products with matches of Category Code ID.

I got an error when I select categoryImage otherwise I got answer.

```
select pc.categoryName, pc.Short_Desc, pc.categoryImage, 
count(p.categoryCodeId) as Total
from tbl_product as p, tbl_productCategory as pc
where p.categoryCodeId = pc.categoryCodeId
group by p.categoryCodeId, pc.categoryName, pc.Short_Desc, pc.categoryImage
order by pc.categoryName
```

How to select all this filed with cateogryImage?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Column 'tbl_productCategory.categoryImage' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Image datatype in Group by clause.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) says:

> Columns of type text, ntext, **and image** cannot be used in
>   group_by_expression.

You can try like this by CAST*ing* it to VARBINARY like

```
select pc.categoryName, pc.Short_Desc, CAST(pc.categoryImage as Varbinary), 
COUNT(p.categoryCodeId)as Total from tbl_product as p, 
tbl_productCategory as pc where p.categoryCodeId=pc.categoryCodeId
group by p.categoryCodeId, pc.categoryName,pc.Short_Desc,
CAST(pc.categoryImage as Varbinary) order by pc.categoryName
```

Comment: I need to select image also

Comment: @UrvishPatel:- Updated my answer. Please check!