# SQL Query to delete duplicate values in a 3 tables inner join with two different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am working with a SQL Server database and I have written the following query:

```
SELECT 
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn,"AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site
INNER JOIN 
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.SiteId = "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Oid
INNER JOIN 
    "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.Oid = "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.OwnerId
WHERE
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'
     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude > 0.0;
```

The query is returning what I need as far as data but it is duplicating some of the data. When I try to add `Distinct` to get rid of the duplicate data...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn,"AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site
INNER JOIN 
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.SiteId = "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Oid
INNER JOIN 
    "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.Oid = "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.OwnerId
WHERE
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'
    AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
    AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude > 0.0;
```

It will not allow me to use it because of this column `"AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes` this column is the actual image data. The error message I get is:

> ERROR: The image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT  because it is not comparable. Error Code: 421

I am trying to get rid of all the duplicate data. To access the database I am using RazorSQL and the remote database is a Microsoft Server 2008 which uses SQL Server.

**UPDATE**

I used the GROUP BY and it looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn,"AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site

INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.SiteId = "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Oid
INNER JOIN "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.Oid = "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.OwnerId

WHERE
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'

     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%BH%'


     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude > 0.0

GROUP BY "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name;
```

Now I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: Column 'AM-Martin.dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude' is  invalid in the
>   select list because it is not contained in  either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause. Error  Code: 8120

Now if I add  some more columns to the group by it keeps saying the same thing for the next column until I get to `"AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes`I get the following error message:

> ERROR: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be  compared or
>   sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE  operator. Error Code: 306

Comment: Using [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) on the right columns instead of a DISTINCT?

Comment: Try to use `correlated subquery` for projecting that image column in `select` statement OR some analytical functions like in oracle `ROW_NUMBER()` for taking one record from duplicates.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect your suggestion @Myonara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to [group by clause is not working with Image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35148582/7039895) all I had to do was add alter the image column wording by CASTing it to VARBINARY like this:

```
SELECT 
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn,**CAST("AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes as Varbinary)**, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site

INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.SiteId = "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Oid
INNER JOIN "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.Oid = "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.OwnerId

WHERE
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'

     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%BH%'


     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude > 0.0

GROUP BY "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn,**CAST("AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes as Varbinary)**, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode;
```

I also have to give @Myonara credit for getting me on the right track with the group by suggestion.