# SQL Server statements imported into Postgres DB now unable to see images - Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, database, postgresql, gmaps4rails

Yesterday I was able to figure out how to use the following query in order to get rid of duplicate results (see [SQL Query to delete duplicate values in a 3 tables inner join with two different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45539408/7039895) for additional info if necessary):

```
SELECT 
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn,**CAST("AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes as Varbinary)**, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site

INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.SiteId = "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Oid
INNER JOIN "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.Oid = "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.OwnerId

WHERE
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'

     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%BH%'


     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude > 0.0

GROUP BY "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn,**CAST("AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes as Varbinary)**, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode;
```

This query allowed me to use `Group By` on the images column. Afterwards I took the data and put it into SQL Statements and imported them into my Postgres SQL DB. When I click on an image value I am unable to open it the message I get in my program (RazorSQL) is:

> Unable to display image

I also checked in the SQL Database Table directly where I ran the query and I am unable to open the images. I suspect it has to do with this line:

```
**CAST("AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes as Varbinary)**
```

Now the issue is the image values are encoded and I do not know how to decode them when I transfer them over like the SQL statement below:

```
CREATE TABLE "map" (
    number varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    latitude float NOT NULL,
    longitude float NOT NULL,
    retiredon timestamp NOT NULL,
    image bytea NOT NULL,
    name varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    zipcode varchar(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO map("number", "latitude", "longitude", "retiredon", "image", "name", "zipcode") VALUES ('BH-0001', 34.059858, -118.376056, '9999-12-31 00:00:00.0', decode('FFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFDB0043000604050605','hex'), 'NB La Cienega Blvd FS Olympic Blvd NEC', '90035');
```

I want to render the images on my website but they appear to be encoded. How do I decode them when I bring them over to postgresql from SQL server in the SQL statement?

**Update**

I tried to render the images in my rails project without the image column everything works smoothly. As soon as I try to render the image data I get the following error message:

> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError

Also see [image: Error Message]

Comment: Hi! Have you considered building a simple app to do this?

Comment: @ignacio can you elaborate please? This is apart of a larger project I'm working on I'm dealing with the back end now.

Comment: Of course Jermaine! I think it would be a good alternative to build an application (I can post a sample in C# if you want) to download the images from MSSQL and then insert them in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I updated my question I don't think I was too clear please check it out see if it makes sense now.

Comment: Let me see if I understand the problem... Could it be possible that the image is not being copied from one database to the other or you are sure the problem is in Rails? I don't have experience in rails but I was thinking about making a query to retrieve the images to the app and then let the connector (Npgsql) to insert them in Postgresql.

Comment: It's being copied over but beforehand it's converted from byte to varbinary so the issue I'm having is converting it back

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider translating your byte to hex before migrating the images into the database as strings and then translating them back to byte form before displaying. See [this blog](http://anthonylewis.com/2011/02/09/to-hex-and-back-with-ruby/) for help in the translations.

Alternatively, you could always try hosting your images on AWS and saving the image url as a string in your database.

Comment: I think you are on to something I am thinking I can write a method in the model that can convert the varbinary back into its original format. I need to think about how though.