# Split SQL query into a nested query (subquery)

Tags: sql-server, database

I am having difficulty converting the following into a sql statement with a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn
    , "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site
    INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.SiteId = "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Oid
WHERE
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'
     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude > 0.0
GROUP BY 
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn
    , "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode;
```

The image data type is giving me issues in regards to trying to use GROUP BY the error I get is:

> ERROR: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or
>   sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator. Error Code: 306

I figured out a solution see my previous question [SQL Query to delete duplicate values in a 3 tables inner join with two different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45539408/7039895) but I am having conversion issues with the images.

My goal is to write a subquery to get the images outside of the main sql statement then join the images afterwards. So far this is what I have:

```
SELECT 
    "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes
    FROM
    (
SELECT 
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site
    INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.SiteId = "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Oid
WHERE
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'
     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude > 0.0
GROUP BY 
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode
) AS a
INNER JOIN "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.Oid = "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.OwnerId;
```

The error I am getting when I run this query is:

> ERROR: The multi-part identifier  "AM-Martin.dbo.CpSm_Face.Oid" could
>   not be bound. Error  Code: 4104

Any help to get this right would be appreciated.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? You tagged it with both postgress and SQL Server. Which one is it?

Comment: Apologies just fixed it but it's SQL Server...

Comment: Why are you using a `GROUP BY`? You don't use any aggregation functions. What are you trying to achieve with the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: When I first wrote the query I was getting a bunch of duplicate data so I had to use group by to get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45539408/7039895

Comment: So to rehash, the `GROUP BY` is to remove duplicates? Do you absolutely need the image byte data in the query? Personally, I feel that using a `GROUP BY` just to remove dupes is a wrong way to approach things. That's what `DISTINCT` is meant for. If the byte data is causing you issues, remove it from the query, add a `DISTINCT`, and then add the byte data once the set is deduplicated. Alternatively, add some `ROW_NUMBER` logic to get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: I need the images to be in the same table...I originally thought of using Distinct but I kept getting error messages because of the image data. This is why I'm thinking of writing a subquery.

Comment: The last part of my question is where I am attempting to do that but I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't properly check the last part of the question. The inner query (which you aliassed as a) seems to be missing the column you need to link the image to the query. In both of your queries, I fail to see how the CpCore_Image table (containing the images) is related to the other tables. Otherwise, it'd be pretty straightforward. `SELECT imageTable.Bytes FROM (SELECT <columns>, <imageID> FROM subqueryTables) a ON imageTable.imageID = a.imageID`. It looks like you're nearly there. If you can somehow post a database diagram, that'd make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Add all columns from a

I cannot seem to be able to edit my comment anymore, but this should do the trick for the second query:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
    , "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes
FROM
    (
SELECT DISTINCT
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode
    , "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.Oid
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site
    INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.SiteId = "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Oid
WHERE
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'
     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude > 0.0
) AS a
INNER JOIN "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image on a.Oid = "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.OwnerId;
```

Note I removed the `GROUP BY` from the inner query, and instead added a DISTINCT to get rid of possible duplicates. However, I cannot test whether this will work, as I don't know your data.

For readability's sake, I would recommend you to alias your tables, rather than repeating the `"AM-MARTIN".dbo.<tablename>` part everywhere (that initially threw me off with regards to finding the proper columns, etc.`).

Example:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
    , b.Bytes
FROM
    (
SELECT DISTINCT
    a_inner.Number
    , a_inner.Latitude
    , a_inner.Longitude
    , b_inner.RetiredOn
    , "a_inner.Name
    , a_inner.Zipcode
    , b_inner.Oid
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site a_inner
    INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face b_inner on b_inner.SiteId = a_inner.Oid
WHERE
    b_inner.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'
     AND b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
     AND b_inner.Latitude > 0.0
) AS a
INNER JOIN "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image b on a.Oid = b.OwnerId;
```

Note that I used `a_inner` and `b_inner` aliases for the subquery. However, you could just as well have used `a` and `b`. I mrerely wanted to ensure you'd see the difference, rather than wondering where the columns were coming from.

Comment: This is great help when I ran the query it went through with no errors only now it does not show the other columns which I was aiming for it to do so. It is only showing me the image column and nothing else. I am assuming it has to do with the join?

Comment: @JermaineSubia My bad. Try my update (I just added a.* to the query)

Comment: This actually worked out I was waiting for it to finish (it is taking forever lots of rows) I did see some initially and it gives me what I was looking for. Next step for me is to import the query results into a postgres DB that is why I initially tagged postgres it was on my mind lol. Thank you so much for your patience and help.

Comment: I also added an example of aliasing to remove the redundant table names. Just to show you th increased readability.

Comment: I can see the difference I am still getting familiar with SQL queries so I can see why aliasing is a great help.

Comment: What do you use to access remote DB's? I am using RazorSQL. I work off of Linux.

Comment: I'm a Microsoft kid, so I use SQL Server Management Studio for pretty much everything I do regards to my MSSQL databases. For MySQL I use WorkBench. For Postgress, I can't quite remember, but something similar. I primarily use the GUI tools provided by the vendors for intellisense' sake.

Comment: quick question I looked at the full data and I am getting duplicate values would you happen to know how to fix it?

Comment: @JermaineSubia The `DISTINCT` should weed out all duplicates. Are the rows returned really duplicate, or is there a specific column that contains a slightly different value? If there is a column in there that is not covered, you might need to add it to the `DISTINCT` part of the query, too. Do you have a few example rows?