# SQL Server DISTINCT and GROUP BY still returning duplicates (subquery format)

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql

Thanks to the community I was able to solve one problem but another was created. When I run this query it returns duplicates:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
    , b.Bytes
FROM
    (
SELECT DISTINCT
    a_inner.Number
    , a_inner.Latitude
    , a_inner.Longitude
    , b_inner.RetiredOn
    , a_inner.Name
    , a_inner.Zipcode
    , b_inner.Oid
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site a_inner
    INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face b_inner on b_inner.SiteId = a_inner.Oid
WHERE
    b_inner.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'
     AND b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
     AND b_inner.Latitude > 0.0
) AS a
INNER JOIN "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image b on a.Oid = b.OwnerId;
```

So I tried to change it up and run this query using GROUP BY  to see if I could get rid of the duplicates but it did not work  I am still getting duplicates:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
    , b.Bytes
FROM
    (
SELECT 
    a_inner.Number
    , a_inner.Latitude
    , a_inner.Longitude
    , b_inner.RetiredOn
    , a_inner.Name
    , a_inner.Zipcode
    , b_inner.Oid
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site a_inner
    INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face b_inner on b_inner.SiteId = a_inner.Oid
WHERE
    b_inner.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'
     AND b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
     AND b_inner.Latitude > 0.0

     GROUP BY 
      a_inner.Number
    , a_inner.Latitude
    , a_inner.Longitude
    , b_inner.RetiredOn
    , a_inner.Name
    , a_inner.Zipcode
    , b_inner.Oid


) AS a
INNER JOIN "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image b on a.Oid = b.OwnerId;
```

Before you ask I do need every column including the images. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My goal is to remove all duplicates.

Here are two examples from my results that are duplicates look at line 93 and 94:

[image: duplicate photo]

I previously ran the query without the subquery but was running into other issues with the image column see [Split SQL query into a nested query (subquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45560100/7039895)

**UPDATE**

I ran the following query and still received duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.*
    , cast(cast(b.Bytes as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) as Bytes
FROM
    (
SELECT 
    a_inner.Number
    , a_inner.Latitude
    , a_inner.Longitude
    , b_inner.RetiredOn
    , a_inner.Name
    , a_inner.Zipcode
    , b_inner.Oid
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site a_inner
    INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face b_inner on b_inner.SiteId = a_inner.Oid
WHERE
    b_inner.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'
     AND b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
     AND b_inner.Latitude > 0.0
) AS a
INNER JOIN "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image b on a.Oid = b.OwnerId;
```

I get the following results:

[image]

If I run this query I get the results that I want:

```
SELECT 
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn,CAST("AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes as Varbinary), "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site

INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.SiteId = "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Oid
INNER JOIN "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image on "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.Oid = "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.OwnerId

WHERE
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'

     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number LIKE N'%BH%'


     AND "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude > 0.0

GROUP BY "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Number,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Latitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Longitude,"AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face.RetiredOn,CAST("AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image.Bytes as Varbinary), "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Name, "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site.Zipcode;
```

But this issue now becomes when I convert the sql results to postgres I cannot render the images any longer this is why I am trying to keep the images data as is without converting to varbinary and bringing them over to postgres.

**UPDATE 2**

I ran amighty's query and what I noticed is that there are multiple images for each owner id they belong to. I need to adjust the query to only showing me one per owner id instead of all of them per owner id.

[image]

Comment: I can assure you that 'distinct' works. If only one column has different values in the records that you consider duplicates, then those records are not identical, therefore the result is not including duplicates.

Comment: The final INNER JOIN opens a whole new opportunity for generating "duplicates".

Comment: Distinct and group by are not intended to be used for squashing duplicates. Duplicates occur because joins are incompletely specified and a subset of values from a table match more than one row in another table. Sometimes this is by design as part of a many:1 relationship but efforts should be made to reduce the many down to just one. To give a ridiculous example, if there is a table with a million rows of identical values in one column and a unique I'd in the other, we do not simply select all the million duplicate values and then think "I'll use distinct to reduce that to one value"..

Comment: Dangit! I thought I had a word of the day with "oncomeyely"  @Jermainesubia show us two entire record in your result set that are duplicates.

Comment: It's what I get for posting from an iPhone, with fat thumbs. Autocorrect does a wonderful job but not wen I catch the return key with said fat thumb; SO then gets a premature comment full of garbage. Not quite sure why I put myself through the pain of using this site in an idevice; it's a bloody awful experience and the dev team are 100% uninterested in improving it

Comment: Nevertheless you created a new word love it lol...I updated my question to include a photo of the results. @CaiusJard thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want 1 image per site and it doesn't matter which image, you can use a cross apply instead of an inner join

```
SELECT 
    a.*
    , b.Bytes
FROM
    (
SELECT DISTINCT
    a_inner.Number
    , a_inner.Latitude
    , a_inner.Longitude
    , b_inner.RetiredOn
    , a_inner.Name
    , a_inner.Zipcode
    , b_inner.Oid
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site a_inner
    INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face b_inner on b_inner.SiteId = a_inner.Oid
WHERE
    b_inner.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'
     AND b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
     AND b_inner.Latitude > 0.0
) AS a
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 
                Bytes 
            FROM "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image b 
            WHERE a.Oid = b.OwnerId) b;
```

You can alter which image you pick for a site with multiple images by adding an "order by" in the cross apply sub query so that the image you want is first, or by adding an additional filter.

Comment: thanks for coming to the rescue I am getting this error ERROR: The multi-part identifier "b.OwnerId" could not be 
bound. Error Code: 4104

Comment: I found it it was just missing the "b" after FROM "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image I am running the results now so far no duplicates I will let you know when I am done.

Answer (score 4):

Without sample data it is hard to say, but my initial thoughts are that your sub-query is returning unique values as the distinct only applies to the sub-query. But there are multiple matches when joining to the second table ("AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image).

The same applies to the "group by", it is only applied to the sub-query giving chance for duplicate returns upon joining to the second table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It makes sense though I just need to figure out how to rewrite the query as to get what I need I have tried it three different ways and each time I think I get what I need but then something else goes wrong I updated my question to hopefully give more clarity and some examples.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get distinct image data type values, you need to cast image data type field to varchar(max)

> e.g.  cast(cast(b.Bytes as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) as Bytes

Please try following updated query. See if it helps

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.*
    , cast(cast(b.Bytes as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) as Bytes
FROM
    (
SELECT 
    a_inner.Number
    , a_inner.Latitude
    , a_inner.Longitude
    , b_inner.RetiredOn
    , a_inner.Name
    , a_inner.Zipcode
    , b_inner.Oid
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site a_inner
    INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face b_inner on b_inner.SiteId = a_inner.Oid
WHERE
    b_inner.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'
     AND b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
     AND b_inner.Latitude > 0.0
) AS a
INNER JOIN "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image b on a.Oid = b.OwnerId;
```

Comment: I ran the query but it still gets duplicates I think I need to remove the subquery and try it as one query following your example.

Comment: Is is possible the Byte values are actually different towards the end.? I'm pretty confident this query won't allow duplicates.

Comment: @Bwarner take a look towards the end of my question I ran the query but I get duplicates check the image.

Comment: Could you show the full values of the Byte columns? I'm just wondering if they are actually different since we can't see the full values in the image.

Comment: Just did some testing and what I found is that for each Oid that an image belongs to there are multiple images for each one. I need to figure out how to only display one image for each one and not all images.